# Problem displaying posts for a category in a custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type called `listing` and a custom taxonomy called `listing_category`. When I navigate to `[DOMAIN]/listing/things-to-do`, I would like the posts with the category of `things-do-do` to display only, however currently ALL posts under the `listing` post type are displayed. I am using the following:

```
$args = array( 
    'posts_per_page'        => get_option('posts_per_page'), 
    'post_type'             => 'listing',
    'tax_query'             => [
        'taxonomy'          => 'listing_category',
        'field'             => 'slug',
        'terms'             => array(81)
    ]
);
```

`81` being the ID of the `things-to-do` category, though I have also tried by slug - still no joy.

Anything I'm missing here?

Comment: WordPress generates the query for you on taxonomy archives, you just need to run the default loop, why are you creating your own query?

Comment: Because for some reason when using the default loop on its own, it returns completely the wrong number of posts (I have 79 posts, but default loop returns 50 for some reason), and also pagination stops working. Perhaps that is another issue, but I am a bit at a loss at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'),   
    'post_type' => 'listing',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'listing_category',
            'field' => 'slug', //can be set to ID
            'terms' => array(81) 
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, all you have done is use the longer syntax for the array..? This doesn't work either unfortunately.